# Where are the root folder names coming from?

Tags: filesystem

```
/bin
/dev
/etc
/lib
/lost+found
/opt
/proc
/root
/sbin
/srv
/sys
/usr
/var
```

Can anyone tell me where they come from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're documented in the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/). You'll find short descriptions for each under the "[Directory structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#Directory_structure)" heading in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).